# Exceeding Rate Limit - Error 429 - Spotify API

Tags: python, python-requests, spotify

I'm trying to pull audio features from Spotify's API. I have a dataset with about 280,000 songs that don't contain the audio features I want so I'm pulling the track ID from each song on my dataset and sending a request in batches of 50 songs with a 1 second delay between requests. Yesterday I had no issue getting about 100,000 of those songs audio features but then it started throwing Error 429 which I know is the rate limit error. However, I've now waited a full day before calling again and now all I am getting is error 429 every time even when I change my batch size to 25 songs and a 5 second delay between requests.

Curious if there's something in my code that is wrong that's making Spotify's API not happy with me. All done in python.

```
#track_uri is column in my dataframe and I split it into track_id then turn into list and split into    batches of 50 

df['track_id'] = df['track_uri'].str.replace('spotify:track:', '', regex=False)
track_ids = df['track_id'].tolist()
batches = [track_ids[i:i + 50] for i in range(0, len(track_ids), 50)]

###token info

def get_track_info(header, track_ids):
    ids = ','.join(track_ids)
    url = f'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/?ids={ids}'
    r = get(url, headers=header)
    return r.json()

for i, batch in enumerate(batches, start=1):
    track_info = get_track_info(header, batch)
    filename = f'audio_features_{i}.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(track_info, f, indent=4)
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong in your code but it seems that you don't respect the Rate Limits specified in the Spotify's developer documentation : https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/rate-limits

`The header of the 429 response will normally include a Retry-After header with a value in seconds.` You could maybe add this to your code to slow down your process.

See this also : https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/Web-API-ratelimit/td-p/5330410